# JDBC getColumnName getColumnLabel DB2

Tags: jdbc, db2, metadata

Is it possible to provide both column name and column label in JDBC `ResultSetMetadata` in DB2 for queries where a real table column is not involved?

```
select substr('Hallo', 1) as greeting from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

I would like to achieve a different column label and column name for the above query.
In this case `getColumnName` and `getColumnLabel` both return the String `"GREETING"`. I would like to set a different column label (e.g. `"Begrüßung"`).

I use DB2 JCC4 Driver and DB2 V9. Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to use getXXX(int position) method and manage column labels on my own

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Normally I do that, too. But in this case I wanted to do a generic approach. Add and remove columns and their labels dynamically to the result set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. The `columnName` in JDBC is defined as the name of the original column. The `columnLabel` is either the original column name (i.e. same value as `columnName`) or - if specified - the `AS` alias of the column.

In your query there is only a `columnLabel` (i.e. `greeting`). What the `columnName` should be in this specific case is actually implementation dependent (it might be an empty string, identical to the `columnLabel` or even something entirely different).